# idhttp.get component doesnt download full HTML File

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-xe7

I am currently working on a program that should download the HTML file of an Wikipedia Page and then convert it from HTML to PDF.

My program so far downloads the HTML file, but without any pictures and the page looks incomplete.

Is there any way I can bring the idhttp.get component from the INDY Package to download the full HTML file?

```
unit Unit3;

  interface

 uses
   Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls,Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, IdBaseComponent, IdComponent, IdTCPConnection,    
   IdHTTP;

type
TForm3 = class(TForm)
  Label1: TLabel;
  Button1: TButton;
  Button2: TButton;
  IdHTTP1: TIdHTTP;
  SpeicherEd: TEdit;
  SaveDialog1: TSaveDialog;
  AuswahlB: TButton;
  NameEd: TEdit;
  procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  procedure NameEdEnter(Sender: TObject);
  procedure AuswahlBClick(Sender: TObject);
 private
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

 var
  Speicherort, Form3: TForm3;

implementation

 uses
  unit2, unit1, Filectrl;
  {$R *.dfm}

 procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var ResponseStream: TFileStream;
 begin
  ResponseStream := TFileStream.Create(SpeicherEd.Text, fmCreate);
 try
   idHTTP1.Get(url, ResponseStream);
 finally
   ResponseStream.Free;
    end;
   ShowMessage('Download abgeschlossen');
  end;

 procedure TForm3.AuswahlBClick(Sender: TObject);
var dir : String;
begin
  dir := ExtractFilePath(Application.ExeName);
 if SelectDirectory ('Bitte ein Verzeichnis auswählen','',Dir)
   then
   SpeicherEd.Text := (dir+'\'+NameEd.text+'.html');

      end;

  procedure TForm3.NameEdEnter(Sender: TObject);
  begin
 NameEd.Text := '';
end;

end.
```

Comment: Indy does not parse the HTML for you at all. It isn't even aware of how HTML is structured. You need to either use a parser and do everything yourself, or resort to something else such as a web browser. Do you understand how dynamic website content works? And then there's script which might change the HTML structure too...

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer you can name any good html parser with nice tuts ? Thanks :)

Comment: I suggest you change your entire approach to use an embedded browser instead. You could use a TWebBrowser or other equivalent solutions such as Chromium Embedded. If all you need to do is print a single page from a website, why go through all the loads of trouble of doing your own parsing?

Comment: TIdHTTP.Get works exactly as it should; it retrieves the HTML. The images that are on a web page are not HTML, and they're not contained in the HTML file itself; they're separate external content that is loaded by the web browser when it is parsing the HTML and finds a reference to external resources. If you want that to happen, you need to do so yourself, or (as @Jerry recommends) use an embedded web browser that already does so for you.